# Can someone explain me the Tom Apostol's definition of limits?

Tags: limits

I wanted to understand the idea of limits and hence I stumbled upon this book by Tom Apostol.Then I read Tom Apostol's Calculus and the definition the book provides is the statement $\lim_{x→a}f(x)=L$
means that we can make the values of $f(x)$
as close as we please to the number $L$, provided that we make the values of $x$
sufficiently close to $a$.
I don't understand what this actually means.What actually is the intuition behind this definition?
.

Comment: You may try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)#In_functions). Most textbooks offer similar explanations to that.

Comment: Isn't there something else also there, with $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ in it, which is the actual definition?

Comment: What I do not understand actually is this explanation that I found:  "phrases like ''can be made as close to as we like or sufficiently close '' are meant to say: if we can make our function values within any neighborhood around L let say N(L) and we've found for any neighborhood around L a sufficient neighborhood around a then we can say limx→af(x) exists"

Comment: Do you understand what a neighbourhood is?

Comment: Yeah, it's a range of values around that input or corresponding output

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an easy example. Let $f(x)=x^2+4$ and let's compute the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)$.

As your book says, to find $L$ we need to take values of $x$ arbitrarily close to $3$. We can compute $f(2.99999999999)$ and $f(3.0000000000001)$ for example. You'll notice the values get closer and closer to $13$. The idea is that we get infinitesimally close to $3$ to find out what the limit is. In this case it is just $f(3)=3^2+4=13$. So $L=13$.

This seems useless from just that example, so let's look at a harder one. Let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$. We are interested in the limit as the $x$ values approach $2$. That is, we want to find $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{1}{x-2}=L$. We can't plug in $g(2)$ into our formula because we would get $g(2)=\frac10$ and you can't divide by zero!

We look at the values from the left of $2$ i.e. values just smaller than it. Plug in $g(1)$, $g(1.5)$, $g(1.9)$, $g(1.9999999)$ etc. into your calculator and notice they keep decreasing.

Now look at the values from the right: $g(3)$, $,g(2.5)$, $g(2.00000001)$ etc. and notice they keep increasing.

This means that the limit at $2$ does NOT exist. There is no number $L$. You can plot this graph on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) to understand why no such number exists.

Limits seem a little useless until you learn about continuity. Continuous functions have the limit defined everywhere in their domain. We can see that $f$ would be continuous and $g$ would not be.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but what actually is the intuition behind this definition?

Comment: @DonAntonio very true! I'll make the edit now

Answer (score 0):

The way I think about it is in terms of a two-player game. The rules are something like this:

1. We start with a function $f(x)$, a point $x_0$ and a target $L$.
2. You then name a positive real number $\epsilon$. It can be big or small, as long as it's greater than zero.
3. I name another positive real number $\delta$.
4. We then draw a box around the graph of $f$, going from $x_0 - \delta$ to $x_0 + \delta$ on the horizontal axis, and from $L - \epsilon$ to $L + \epsilon$ on the vertical axis.
5. If $f(x)$ has any points above or below the box (except possibly $f(x_0)$ itself), then you win. Otherwise, if I've managed to trap $f(x)$ inside the box, I win.

If I have a strategy to name a value of $\delta$ in response to your $\epsilon$ that *always* lets me win, then we say that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = L$.

[image]

In the diagram above, you can see an example - the blue lines are at $x = x_0$ and $ y = L$, and the dotted lines show one particular choice of $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ that successfully trap $f(x)$ inside the box. Notice that if you choose a smaller value of $\epsilon$, then you just need to find a corresponding value of $\delta$ to keep trapping the function. On the other hand, if we moved the $y = L$ line to a different height then at some point you'll be able to find a value of $\epsilon$ that *never* lets you trap $f(x)$ inside the box - for example, if we move it to $y = 0$ and choose a small value of $\epsilon$ then there will always be a part of $f(x)$ that sits above the line regardless of how narrow we try to draw the lines around $x = x_0$.

Comment: By box, do you mean the common region enclosed by those four lines?

Comment: Yes, that's the box I mean.